# Pandas creating future windows and taking first non-NA within each window, then shifting downwards

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
              A    B    C    D
01-01-2021  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
02-01-2021  2.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
03-01-2021  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
04-01-2021  3.0  2.0  NaN  1.0
05-01-2021  2.0  3.0  NaN  3.0
06-01-2021  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
07-01-2021  1.0  1.0  3.0  2.0
08-01-2021  2.0  2.0  1.0  3.0
09-01-2021  3.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
```

I want to create future-looking windows of width `N=6` for each cell and depending on the number of valid (non-NA) values in the cells of these windows, either return the first non-NA value in the window shifted by `N=5` downwards, or a `NaN`.

In the example dataframe, column `A` is a fully valid one without any `NaN` values. We create the first future window with width of `N=6` for `01-01-2021` which includes dates from `01-01-2021` to `06-01-2021`. There are no `NaN` values, i.e. the total number of valid values (`6`) is above a threshold of `thresh=3`. This way, our the first value in column `A` in our resulting dataframe will be `1.0` on `06-01-2021`: we simply take the uppermost valid (non-NA) value in the window we created, and move it down by 5 days, from `01-01-2021` to `06-01-2021`. The rest of the values in this column are analogous. This way, therefore, column `A` will simply be shifted downwards by `5` days.

Column `B` has its first value missing (`NaN`). This way, our first value in the resulting dataframe will still appear on `06-01-2021` but it will be the value corresponding to `02-01-2021` from the original dataframe. Importantly, the second value in the resulting dataframe (on `07-01-2021`) will be identical to the value on the day before, i.e. both will be `1.0` in the resulting dataframe.

In column `C`, the first and second future windows do not have enough non-NA values, therefore the values on `06-01-2021` and `07-01-2021` in the resulting dataframe will be `NaN`s. On `08-01-2021`, the resulting dataframe will be `1.0` since that is the first non-NA value in the time window created for 5 days back, on `03-01-2021`.

Here is how the resulting dataframe should look like:

```
              A    B    C    D
06-01-2021  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
07-01-2021  2.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
08-01-2021  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
09-01-2021  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
10-01-2021  2.0  3.0  1.0  3.0
11-01-2021  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
12-01-2021  1.0  1.0  3.0  2.0
13-01-2021  2.0  2.0  1.0  3.0
14-01-2021  3.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
```

I am aware of pandas's `rolling` functionality and that it has a `min_periods` parameter that really resembles to the functionality that I am trying to apply here. I also know that `groupby` has a `first` method that is also partly what I'd need here. However, I am not sure how to connect the dots. My initial idea was shifting the entire dataframe upwards by 6 and use `rolling` with `min_periods`, however, `rolling` has no `first` method (unlike `groupby`) and using `df.shift(-6)` removes the first rows in my dataframe that would be important to determine the values.

Answer (score 0):

- It sounds like the future-looking window of width `N=6` with `thresh=3` is exactly the same as filling values at most 3 days previously. The command `pd.fillna` was made for this. Specify `bfill` to fill upwards (`axis=0`) a maximum of `limit=3`.
- Turning the date column into datetime objects makes it easy to turn them 5 days into the future with `DateOffset`.

```
dt=pd.read_csv("data.txt", header=0)
dt["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(dt["Date"], dayfirst=True) + pd.DateOffset(days=5)
print(dt.fillna(method="bfill", axis=0, limit=3))

        Date    A    B    C    D
0 2021-01-06  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
1 2021-01-07  2.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
2 2021-01-08  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
3 2021-01-09  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
4 2021-01-10  2.0  3.0  1.0  3.0
5 2021-01-11  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
6 2021-01-12  1.0  1.0  3.0  2.0
7 2021-01-13  2.0  2.0  1.0  3.0
8 2021-01-14  3.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
```

**Data**

```
Date,A,B,C,D
01-01-2021,1.0,NaN,NaN,NaN
02-01-2021,2.0,1.0,NaN,NaN
03-01-2021,2.0,2.0,NaN,NaN
04-01-2021,3.0,2.0,NaN,1.0
05-01-2021,2.0,3.0,NaN,3.0
06-01-2021,1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0
07-01-2021,1.0,1.0,3.0,2.0
08-01-2021,2.0,2.0,1.0,3.0
09-01-2021,3.0,2.0,1.0,2.0
```